# bounded and unital operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎let‎ ‎$ T \in B ( H ) $‎be ‎invertible.‎

**how ‎can ‎help ‎me ‎to ‎prove:‎**

> $ ‎\parallel ‎T‎ ‎\parallel =‎ ‎‎\parallel T‎‎‎^{‎-1‎} ‎‎‎‎‎\parallel‎‎‎ $ ‎if ‎only ‎if‎ ‎$ T $ ‎is ‎Unital?‎

‎$ T $ ‎is unital means ‎$ T ‎T‎^{*} = T‎^{*} T = I
‎$ ‎‎and ‎$‎B ( H ) ‎‎$‎means bounded operator on Hilbert space‎‎‎‎.

thanks ‎for ‎your ‎attention

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not true:
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}\qquad T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac12&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$
Clearly $\|T\|=\|T^{-1}\|$ but neither is unital.